# Modern C++ iteration over pointer to vector

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

For this code

```
std::vector<FOO> foo_vec;

for (auto &f : foo_vec){
}
```

What if we have

`std::vector<FOO> *foo_vec;`
?

Can I use a similar notation with pointer to vector ?

Comment: You can get a reference to vector like in first example by dereferencing pointer.

Comment: Generally one should not have a pointer to a vector.  That said `(*ptr_to_vector)` gives you a reference to the vector.

Comment: `for (auto &f : *foo_vec)`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was just hoping to avoid dereferencing the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the pre-condition that the pointer actually points to a vector, you can use the indirection operator to get an lvalue to the pointed vector: `*foo_vec`. This vector lvalue can be use like any other vector lvalue, and can be used in a range-for loop.